# Backpack for Laravel: how to add 'delete' per-line button conditionally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've a parent model which can have n childs

So I want to show delete button ONLY if it has not children (hasMany relationship must return 0 records).

How can I show 'delete' link in each lines of a table (in the list operation), but ONLY if a condition is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option I see is to use a custom view for the `Delete` button, instead of the one in the package. Depending on how wide you want this change to be made:

**A. If you want to do that across all CRUDs** - it's easy, just [publish the view](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#publish-a-column-field-filter-button-and-modify-it) by running:

```sh
php artisan backpack:publish crud/buttons/delete
```

This will place the file in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons`, for you to change however you like. Inside [the delete button view](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php) you have the current entry available as `$entry` so you can do something like `$entry->children()->count()` if you want. Be mindful that this will be run ONCE PER LINE so if you show 50 lines in the table for example, you'd need to find a way to optimize this.

**B. If you want to do that for just one CRUD** (eg. do it for Categories but not for Products), then you can do the same thing (publish the button view), but rename the button to something different like `delete_if_no_children.blade.php` so that it doesn't get used automatically for all CRUDs. Then use it only inside the controllers you want, inside `setupListOperation()`, by removing the "stock" delete button and adding yours:

```php
// using the Backpack array syntax
$this->crud->removeButton('delete');
$this->crud->addButton('line', 'delete', 'view', 'crud::buttons.delete_if_no_children', 'end');

// using the Backpack fluent syntax
CRUD::button('delete')->view('crud::buttons.delete_if_no_children');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
withCount('children')
```

Docs: [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

---

Additionally you can wrap delete buttons with blade directive

```
@can('destroy', $model) disabled @endcan
```

Docs: [@can](https://laravel.com/docs/authorization#via-blade-templates)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Model;
use App\Models\User;

class ModelPolicy
{
    public function update(User $user, Model $model)
    {
        return $model->children_count === 0;
    }
}
```

Docs: [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/authorization#writing-policies)

Comment: sorry but my question is specific for 'backpack for laravel'. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `hasMany` relationship will return an empty `Collection` when there are no associated records. You can then proceed to call `isEmpty()` on the collection to verify there are no child records (children).

Example in PHP:

```
$parents = Parent::with('children')->get();
```

And then in your template you can do:

```
@foreach($parents as $parent)
    @if($parent->children->isEmpty())
        <button>Delete</button>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry but my question is specific for 'backpack for laravel'. But thanks